# "Mai ... fu/furono ..." oppure "mai ... non fu/furono ..."?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-choice

Quale tra questi due costrutti è quello che si usa in italiano per dare alla frase un senso superlativo in modo enfatico: "mai ... fu/furono ..." oppure "mai ... non fu/furono ..."? (o un altro verbo coniugato al passato al posto del verbo "essere").

Per esempio, se sto scrivendo su certe scelte che si avrebbero dovuto fare e voglio esprimere che tali scelte furono le più difficili di tutte quelle fatte fino a quel momento, quale tra le seguenti sarebbe la frase giusta?

> - Mai tali scelte furono così difficili.
> - Mai tali scelte non furono così difficili.

Comment: Le due frasi hanno significati opposti. Qual è la tua domanda?

Comment: @Josh61: Significati oposti?

Comment: @Josh61: Immagino che io stia comparando l'italiano con le due lingue che conosco di più: il catalano e il castigliano. In catalano si usano costrutti con "mai ... no" che in castigliano corrispondono a frasi con "nunca" ma senza "no". Per esempio, per esprimere che una certa parola era la più adatta di tutte, in catalano si può scrivere: "mai una paraula no havia estat tan encertada com ...". Questa frase in castigliano sarebbe: "nunca una palabra fue tan acertada como ..." senza no.

Comment: Nell'esempio, se voglio esprimere che le scelte furono le più difficili di tutte quelle fatte fino a quel momento, quale sarebbe la forma giusta?

Comment: La prima significa che scelte così difficili non furono mai fatte prima. La seconda, con la doppia negazione, mai/non, significa che le scelte furono facili, anche se espresso in maniera insolita.

Comment: @Josh61: Ho modificato il testo della mia domanda. Non so se adesso sono riuscita a esprimermi un po' meglio.

Comment: La prima frase esprime il concetto che descrivi, la seconda significa il contrario come abbiamo già detto.

Comment: @Josh61: Cambiando l'ordine delle parole sarebbe "tali scelte non furono mai così difficili", no?

Comment: Si, *non furono mai*, oppure, *mai furono*.

Comment: Le due frasi *non* hanno significati opposti (si veda la definizione del [_De Mauro_](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/mai), accezione 1b). _Mai_ di solito si colloca alla fine della frase o, nei tempi composti, tra l’ausiliare e il participio passato. Se è posto all’inizio, in posizione marcata (_enfatica_ come dice il _De Mauro_), generalmente non richiede la negazione _non_ prima del verbo. La negazione, però, può essere presente per un sovrappiú d’enfasi (si veda il [_Treccani_](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mai/), accezione 2b).

Comment: Nota che *così difficili mai scelte non furono* è aulico, ma non incomprensibile. Trovo *mai scelte non furono così difficili* indigeribile. Le possibilità sono due: *non* all'inizio e *mai* successivo a rafforzare oppure *mai* iniziale e nessuna negazione.

Comment: Capisco, @egreg, grazie. Ma penso che qualcuno dovrebbe scrivere la risposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cerco di fare qui un riassunto di tutto quello che ho ricavato  dai vostri commenti.

I costrutti usati solitamente in italiano sono *non* + verbo + *mai* (nei tempi composti, "mai" si colloca tra l’ausiliare e il participio passato) o, per dare un valore enfatico alla frase, *mai* ... + verbo senza "non". Si veda la definizione del [dizionario De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/mai), accezione 1b.

Nell'esempio della domanda, queste due possibilità sarebbero:

> - Tali scelte non furono mai così difficili.
> - Mai tali scelte furono così difficili.

Secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mai/) (accezione 2b), nella seconda costruzione si può aggiungere il "non" per un sovrappiù d’enfasi, ottenendo la frase "Mai tali scelte non furono così difficili". Un altro esempio tratto dal Treccani è: "Mai non si vide una cosa simile". Quest'ultima possibilità, però, si usa talmente poco nell'italiano attuale che sarebbe comprensibile a pochi ed è pertanto sconsigliabile.

Answer (score -1):

Dipende cosa vuoi esprimere, in larga parte. La prima, forma abbastanza magniloquente, indica che le scelte che si stanno affrontando sono le più difficili mai fatte. La seconda esprime esattamente il contrario perché in questo caso le due negazioni si annullano a vicenda, ma il costrutto non può definirsi corretto in italiano. Se invece la frase fosse stata costruita così: «Tali scelte non furon mai così difficili», avrebbe espresso lo stesso significato della prima da te scritta.

In definitiva, credo il tuo dubbio sia se in italiano si usi o meno il mai con un altra negazione. La risposta è: entrambe, ma di solito è meglio usarne solo una, dato che le doppie negazioni non rispondono a regole precise, per esempio in «Non mi fu mai così chiaro» si verifica esattamente l'opposto.

Comment: Cosa vuoi dire con "si verifica esattamente l'opposto"?

Comment: No, le due frasi hanno esattamente lo stesso significato. _Mai_, se posto in posizione iniziale, può comparire anche da solo, senza la negazione. La negazione dà alla frase un’enfasi aggiuntiva ([_Treccani_](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mai/), acc. 2b).

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu - la seconda negazione nella seconda frase crea solo confusione e sarebbe chiara a pochi. Tu quale delle due frasi useresti? Direi che il mai seguito da un altra negazione sia di uso letterario. Nel linguaggio comune ti chiederebbero cosa intendi dire!

Comment: @Josh61: Secondo me, una cosa è dire che nel linguaggio comune è meglio usare la prima frase perché il secondo costrutto si usa tanto poco che sarebbe chiaro a pochi e un'altra diversa è affermare che le due frasi hanno significati opposti.

Comment: @Charo - sono d'accordo, ma la lingua è usata per capirsi. Se tu usi la seconda costruzione penso che potresti facilmente essere fraintesa. Up to you.

Comment: D'accordo @Josh61! Io mi riferisco al modo di scrivere la risposta.

Comment: Immagino che la questione abbia qualcosa a che vedere con l'evoluzione della lingua. Come ho già detto, il costrutto con "mai ... no" si usa in catalano, ma non in castigliano.

Comment: Si, andrebbe rifatta con le considerazioni fatte finora.

Comment: Un modo di dire catalano è "mai no plou al gust de tothom" (letteralmente, "non piove mai al gusto di tutti").