# Posizione di "qui" in una frase

Tags: adverbs, word-order

Quando ho scritto la prima frase di [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5548/707) ho avuto il dubbio su quale fosse la posizione giusta dell'avverbio "qui":

> - Cerco di fare *qui* un riassunto di tutto quello che ho ricavato dai vostri commenti.
> - *Qui* cerco di fare un riassunto di tutto quello che ho ricavato dai vostri commenti.
> - Cerco di fare un riassunto *qui* di tutto quello che ho ricavato dai vostri commenti.
> - Cerco *qui* di fare un riassunto di tutto quello che ho ricavato dai vostri commenti.

Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il mio dubbio?

Comment: A orecchio la prima è   le espressioni più naturale.  La seconda da molta enfasi al *qui*.  La terza e la quarta sono più discorsive, da parlato più che da scritto.

Comment: La seconda frase suona come un'opposizione e mi aspetto che segua qualcosa come *nell'altro articolo discuto per esteso*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ti posso dire, da italiano, come interpreto quelle quattro frasi.

> Cerco di fare qui un riassunto di tutto quello che ho ricavato dai vostri commenti.

"Qui", "in questo articolo/post".

> Qui cerco di fare un riassunto di tutto quello che ho ricavato dai vostri commenti.

Come sopra, però questa non suona molto bene. È corretta, ma la prima suona meglio.

> Cerco di fare un riassunto qui di tutto quello che ho ricavato dai vostri commenti.

Questa la considero sbagliata. "di tutto quello" è **separato** da "riassunto", a cui si riferisce. Decisamente da evitare.

> Cerco qui di fare un riassunto di tutto quello che ho ricavato dai vostri commenti.

In questa frase, invece, "qui" lo potremmo sostituire con: *con* questo post. Quindi tu fai un riassunto *tramite* il post piuttosto che *nel* post. Oppure un'altra sfumatura è interpretarlo come "in questo momento".

Certo, le sfumature disponibili sono più di una, e spesso a seconda del contesto userei una forma rispetto ad un'altra. Comunque sia, l'importante è che eviti la terza. Le altre sono tutte accettabili.

Answer (score 1):

Secondo me vanno bene tutte e quattro, a "orecchio" io userei la prima e la quarta che mi piacciono di più. La seconda andrebbe bene come conclusione di un testo svolto nelle righe precedenti perché dà molto risalto alla parola "qui"...La terza risulta un po' strana, il "qui" risulta un po' slegato, meglio evitarla.