# Differenze di uso tra gli avverbi "tanto" e "talmente"

Tags: word-usage, difference, adverbs

"Tanto" e "talmente" possono essere usati come avverbi. Quando ho redatto [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5548/707), ho scritto la frase

> Quest'ultima possibilità, però, si usa *tanto* poco nell'italiano attuale che sarebbe comprensibile a pochi ed è pertanto sconsigliabile

che poi mi è stata corretta così:

> Quest'ultima possibilità, però, si usa *talmente* poco nell'italiano attuale che sarebbe comprensibile a pochi ed è pertanto sconsigliabile.

Non capisco bene quali siano le differenze di uso tra gli avverbi "tanto" e "talmente". Me le potreste spiegare?

Comment: Invece di *talmente* puoi adoperare *così*.

Comment: @Charo, in altri contesti trovi anche "talmente tanto", per esempio Andeotti disse una volta "Amo talmente tanto la Germania che ne preferivo due"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guardando lo storico delle modifiche... Qualcuno ha prima ristrutturato la tua frase in modo da eliminare la costruzione `tanto`...`che`, forse perché la presenza di `poco` immediatamente dopo può sembrare una nota stonata. Poi tu hai ripristinato questa costruzione usando `talmente`. Non saprei, secondo me è un lavoro inutile, perché `tanto`...`che` va bene:

> 5 In correlazione con “che” o “da”, introduce una propos. consecutiva:
>   dice tante sciocchezze che non lo sopporto; ha t. bisogno che non si
>   vergogna di chiedere; tante risate da scoppiare; ho tanta paura da non
>   sapere cosa fare

Fonte: http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/T/tanto.php

Quanto alle differenze tra `tanto` e `talmente`, il primo è molto più versatile (come certamente saprai), `talmente` fa quasi sempre da antecedente per `che` o `da` in questa costruzione qui, anche se qualcuno di tanto in tanto lo usa da solo (`Ah, sono talmente arrabbiato!`).

**EDIT**: sulla questione avverbio/aggettivo, credo manchi solo l'esempio. Io dico tranquillamente `Carla si è dimostrata tanto brava che si merita [o da meritarsi] un premio`.

Comment: Negli esempi che hai riportato, "tanto" è un aggettivo e non un avverbio. La mia domanda è su "tanto" usato come avverbio.

Comment: Per quanto riguarda lo storico delle modifiche che hai menzionato, la soluzione con "talmente" non l'ho scritta veramente io, ma mi è stata suggerita nel commento alla prima correzione.

Comment: @Charo : sullo storico delle modifiche, mi era sfuggito il suggerimento. Su avverbio/aggettivo, credo manchi solo l'esempio. Io dico tranquillamente `Carla si è dimostrata tanto brava che si merita [o da meritarsi] un premio`.